# Раскодировать UCS2

Tags: javascript, кодировка, перекодировка

Вот это текст в UCS2:

> 004F0043005400410054004F004B002000380033002E0032003700200070002E0020003700200434043D043504390020043C04430437044B043A0438002E0020041104350437043B0438043C04380442043D043E002004380020043104350441043F043B04300442043D043E003A0020002A0036003200360023

Через онлайн конвертер  все работает и текст переводится в нормальную кириллицу.
[Ссылка тут.](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288)

Как мне в JS перекодировать UCS-2 в кириллицу?

Comment: `'OCTATOK 83.27 p. 7 дней музыки. Безлимитно и бесплатно: *626#'`

Comment: Кстати, слово «Остаток» написано латинскими буквами. Кто-то пытается что-то сэкономить?

Answer (score 1):

Это строка UCS-2 в шестнадцатеричной записи. В UCS-2 каждая «буква» (code point) кодируется двумя байтами, т.е. в этой строке каждые четыре символа это одна буква. Например `004F` это латинская большая «O», а `0434` это русская буква «д».

Значит нужно просто разбить эту строку на четвёрки и преобразовать их в буквы. Например так:

```
const s = '004F0043005400410054004F004B....';
let result = '';
for (let k = 0; k < s.length; k += 4) {
    // берём очередные 4 символа
    let hexcode = s.slice(k, k + 4);
    // Преобразуем в число из 16-чного представления
    let code = parseInt(hexcode, 16);
    // Получаем букву по номеру в Unicode
    result += String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

А если вспомнить, что в JS есть старая добрая функция `unescape`, то всё это можно записать одной строчкой (*не рекомендую так делать*):

```
const s = '004F0043005400410054004F004B....';
let result = unescape(s.replace(/(....)/g, '%u$1'));
```

Разбор работы второго варианта оставляю в качестве домашнего задания.

Comment: Благодарю. Все заработало!!!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста , как текст в UCS-2 конвертировать ?
по тойже схеме

Comment: @user366718 задайте новый вопрос